# Event ID 10 - Windows Event Viewer

Tags: mysql

I receive the following error every bootup which does a few minutes crash. It then also can occur later on which does a complete crash and it will not unfreeze until I restart.

> Event filter with query "SELECT * FROM __InstanceModificationEvent WITHIN 60 WHERE TargetInstance ISA "Win32_Processor" AND TargetInstance.LoadPercentage > 99" could not be reactivated in namespace "//./root/CIMV2" because of error 0x80041003. Events cannot be delivered through this filter until the problem is corrected.

The following URL does display some code to run: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/950375 but does this solve the problem, or does it actually just hide the errors? I need the crashes to stop and they do occur when I receive an Event 10 ID error.

Answer (score 0):

It's unlikely in my opinion that the crash is a result of this error.  You could at least rule this out by running the script suggested.

If that does not solve the crashes, you need to dig a bit in the Event Viewer to find out what's going on before the crash.  Sounds like a malfunctioning piece of hardware.  Failing boot drive, bad RAM?  Run diagnostics on them.

Make sure you are running current antivirus software as well.  Run a full scan if that's not been done for a while.

Comment: I run my scans regularly. I did read somewhere that another person also had this error. The strange thing is, this error is shown at the times my pc crashes. So I'm not sure. This is teh only error that pops up in the event viewer.

It shouldn't be the boot drive, as 2 hours maybe more after booting it ... the crash can occur then. I did do a memtest a while back when this was happening - it shown that nothing was wrong. If it was bad ram, something is triggering it to happen rarely. Other than the crashes, my pc runs smoothly. It knows there is 8GB Ram.

Comment: I'll try the script, it looked from what it stated that it'll only "hide" the error. In my honest opinion, errors are to be fixed, not ignored.

Comment: I tried the script, I also looked for more errors elsewhere - There is a critical one. Source - Kernel-Power. EVENT ID 41. This also looks to be the problem.

The system has rebooted without cleanly shutting down first. This error could be caused if the system stopped responding, crashed, or lost power unexpectedly.

Last logged around the time the crash last happened earlier. Ahhh!

Comment: Apparently not. That only occurs when the pc did not shut down properly - clicking the reset button my tower would of caused this.

Answer (score 0):

This WMI error is a known issue, and it's not related to your crashing problem.

From Microsoft's [KB2545227](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2545227):

> Cause:
>
> This originated in the Windows 7 SP1 DVD/ISO creation process. There
>   was an issue in the creation process that caused a WMI registration to
>   remain in the DVD/ISO. Since the registration is designed to work only
>   during the DVD/ISO creation process, it fails to run on a live system
>   and causes these events. **These events are not indicative of any issue
>   in the system and can be safely ignored**. If however you want to
>   prevent these events from getting generated and want to remove this
>   specific WMI registration manually, please follow the steps mentioned
>   in this article for running the workaround script.

They offer a FixIt to fix the problem, plus manual instructions:

1. In Notepad create a new document named Workaround.txt
2. Copy the following script into notepad:

---

```
strComputer = "."

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
& "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" _
& strComputer & "\root\subscription")

Set obj1 = objWMIService.ExecQuery("select * from __eventfilter where name='BVTFilter' and query='SELECT * FROM __InstanceModificationEvent WITHIN 60 WHERE TargetInstance ISA ""Win32_Processor"" AND TargetInstance.LoadPercentage > 99'")

For Each obj1elem in obj1

set obj2set = obj1elem.Associators_("__FilterToConsumerBinding")

set obj3set = obj1elem.References_("__FilterToConsumerBinding")

For each obj2 in obj2set

 WScript.echo "Deleting the object"

 WScript.echo obj2.GetObjectText_

 obj2.Delete_

next

For each obj3 in obj3set

 WScript.echo "Deleting the object"

 WScript.echo obj3.GetObjectText_

 obj3.Delete_

next

WScript.echo "Deleting the object"

WScript.echo obj1elem.GetObjectText_

obj1elem.Delete_

Next
```

3. Save the text as `Workaround.vbs`
4. Close Notepad
5. Open an elevated command prompt:

   a. Click on start

   b. Click on Programs

   c. Right-Click on Command Prompt

   d. Choose run as administrator
6. Change Directory to the one containing `workaround.vbs` (Example `CD c:\users\%username%`)
7. Run `cscript workaround.vbs`

After running the script the Event ID 10 errors related to this event should stop occurring. This does not remove any of the existing entries in the Event log, they would need to be manually cleared out of the application event log.